# OpenGL raster text disappears behind background

Tags: opengl, text, background

I am drawing a quad as a background so I can apply a gradient.  Details of how I'm doing this are found in a similar question:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064840](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064840/opengl-background-dissappears-with-certain-polygon-modes)

The 2D raster text (screen text) is drawn as expected without the gradient background.  However, when the gradient background is drawn, the text disappears (I'm assuming behind the background quad).

¿ Any ideas ?

I am creating the font by calling

```
wglUseFontBitmaps HDC, 32, 96, FontID
```

and the text is drawn using

```
glRasterPos3d X, Y, Z
glListBase FontID - 32

glPushAttribute GL_LIST_BIT

Dim B() As Byte
B = StrConv(TextString, vbFromUnicode)  
glCallLists Len(TextString), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, B(0)

glPopAttribute GL_LIST_BIT
```

Note that my 3D text is being drawn successfully in all cases using

```
wglUseFontOutlines HDC, 0, 255, FontID, 0, 0, WGL_FONT_LINES, GMF(0)
  or
wglUseFontOutlines HDC, 0, 255, FontID, 0, 0, WGL_FONT_POLYGONS, GMF(0)
```

and it's equivalent drawing routines.

> **Edit:  Solved**
>
> **I was popping a matrix I shouldn't have been popping.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should disable the Z-buffer when drawing the text with

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```

and enable it after you're done with the text with

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```

Is that OpenGL inside Visual Basic? Absolutely Hideous...

Comment: Disabling the Z-buffer did not fix the issue.  And yes, OpenGL with VB6 is absolutely hideous.

Comment: With no Z-buffer, nothing is going to be behind anything. so it the text is the last thing you draw you should definitely see it. Could you be more specific as to how it fails to work?

Comment: In my original attempt I reversed glDisable and glEnable.  Now that I have correctly followed your suggestion the text appears over the background.  However, this is not an optimal solution because now the text always appears, even when it is behind a (non-background) object in my scene.